# URL Redirection From Custom Type to Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, redirect

I have a problem with Wordpress. I have custom type "review" and I migrate all its content into posts successfully. But I don't know how to redirect the old URL into new URL.

The old URL format: **www.mysite.com/review/this-is-post**

The new URL after migration into posts: **www.mysite.com/this-is-post**

How to make redirection from old URL into new URL? So, if visitor visit the old URL, they automatically redirect to new URL.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use a [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) in your .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch Permanent ^/review/(.*) /$1
```